# User Context values doesnt change in child component

Tags: reactjs, authentication, use-context

I am trying to redirect user in case user is not authenticated and vice versa
so, I have the directory structure as follow

**myproject**
src
App.js
UserContext.js
routes
index.js
route.js
pages
Dashboard
index.js
authentication
login.js

In my app.js i do a call and get my authentication token
and set auth to true and pass it in user context but it has the default values and i cannot redirect currently redirecting with only window.location.href

my code for usercontext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";
export const UserContext = createContext(null)
```

APP.js

```
const App = props => {
const [user,setUser] = React.useState(null)
var [auth,setAuth] = React.useState(false)
const isAuthenticated = ()=>
{
   var isAdmin = true;
    axios.get(`/verifyToken`).then((response)=>{
      console.log(response.data.auth)
    setUser({...response.data.user})
   
    setAuth(response.data.auth)
      console.log(response.data.user)
  
    })
  

  
}
useEffect(() => {

 
  isAuthenticated()
    console.log(auth)


},[]);
  function getLayout() {
    let layoutCls = VerticalLayout
    switch (props.layout.layoutType) {
      case "horizontal":
        layoutCls = HorizontalLayout
        break
      default:
        layoutCls = VerticalLayout
        break
    }
    return layoutCls
  }

  const Layout = getLayout()
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <UserContext.Provider value={{user,setUser,auth,setAuth,isAuthenticated}}>
          {publicRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
            <Authmiddleware
              path={route.path}
              layout={NonAuthLayout}
              component={route.component}
              key={idx}
              isAuthProtected={auth}
              exact
            />
          ))}

          {authProtectedRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
            <Authmiddleware
              path={route.path}
              layout={Layout}
              component={route.component}
              key={idx}
              isAuthProtected={auth}
              exact
            />
          ))}
          </UserContext.Provider>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

**My index.js file has component and routes names array which i am looping above
and this is my route.js**

```
const Authmiddleware = ({
  component: Component,
  layout: Layout,
  isAuthProtected,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
     


      return (
        <Layout>
          <Component {...props} />
        </Layout>
      )
    }}
  />
)

Authmiddleware.propTypes = {
  isAuthProtected: PropTypes.bool,
  component: PropTypes.any,
  location: PropTypes.object,
  layout: PropTypes.any, 
}

export default Authmiddleware;
```

So, now If in my dashboard.js I try to access user on wan tto redirect if auth is false it only has default values of user and auth
I am fetching as follows in dashboard.js

```
import {UserContext} from '../../UserContext'

 const {user,setUser,auth,setAuth,isAuthenticated} = React.useContext(UserContext)

React.useEffect(()=>{
if(auth == false){
window.location.href='/login'
//IT TAKES ME LOGIN EVERYTIME AT IT IS ONLY GETTING DEFAULT VALUE THAT IS FALSE

},[])
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

If i place the isAuthenticated() function call in every component it works
but that would be like so many lines of code same in every component
What is the way to go with?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone facing the same issue I resolved it by
bringing out

```
 <UserContext.Provider></UserContext.Provider>
```

outside the switch

```
          <UserContext.Provider value={{user,setUser,auth,setAuth,isAuthenticated}}>
  <Switch>
</Switch>
          </UserContext.Provider value={{user,setUser,auth,setAuth,isAuthenticated}}>
```

I FOUND THE REASON HERE: https://coderedirect.com/questions/324089/how-to-use-context-api-with-react-router-v4

The reason posted in answer here was that Switch expects routes directly.